# Running foreach loop in powershell prompts for credentials every loop?

Tags: powershell

I've implemented a short Powershell snippet to mass rename computers in my Domain. It reads a CSV file with two columns, OldName and NewName, and loops across the list to change the name.

This works on paper, however every time I run the script it gives me a prompt to enter a password for every computer that it loops through. Is there a way to only use my credentials once for the whole script? Thank you.

```
$a = Import-Csv C:\File.csv -Header OldName, NewName
Foreach ($Computer in $a) {Rename-Computer -ComputerName $Computer.OldName -NewName $Computer.NewName -DomainCredential Domain\Admin01 -Force -Restart}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution would be to store your [`PSCredential` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) before running the loop and feed the cmdlet said object. You can use [`Get-Credential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7.2) as an easy alternative to request credentials:

```bash
$Csv  = Import-Csv C:\File.csv -Header OldName, NewName
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential Domain\Admin01
foreach($Computer in $Csv) {
    Rename-Computer -ComputerName $Computer.OldName -NewName $Computer.NewName -DomainCredential $cred -Force -Restart
}
```